# How can we use numpy.npv to group by item and calculate NPVs per group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I just stumbled across numpy.npv today. Here is some documentation.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.npv.html

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':1000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':7000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':6000, 'Building':'Casino'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':9000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':6000, 'Revenue':10000, 'Building':'Casino'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

I'm wondering how to get NPV, based on Revenue, for Stadium and Casino. So, maybe it would be another dataframe with one NPV for Stadium and one NPV for Casino. Or, maybe it would be a list. Not sure. Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `df.groupby("Building")["Revenue"].apply(lambda x: npf.npv(rate=0.1, values=x))` ?

Comment: That's perfect. I figured it was some kind of lambda x: thing. I never really understood that thing. I guess I need to set aside some time to learn how it works. Thanks so much!